# Dynamic element name for xml schema

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I want to set element name dynamically that means it's come from database,

for eg, Afdeling,Fabrikant,Promo etc.

How can i set this in xml schema currently i have set this static.

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"  name="Afdeling"    type="xs:string" />
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"  name="Fabrikant"   type="xs:string" />
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"  name="Promo"       type="xs:string" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an element wildcard: `<xs:any>`. You can't then constrain the element name any further in the schema (except to make it appear in a particular namespace) unless you use XSD 1.1 assertions.